# component livechat in angular not working

Tags: javascript

I am using an online chat widget that was provided to me to implement it in Angular, for that they gave me a script to arrive and use but I have 2 problems.

1. I want to put the widget in my index.html, this works fine but on mobile the chat is not visible
2. I also tried to put it in the app.component.html but it is not displayed there by any means.

Is there a way to manipulate this script so that the char bubble appears on all devices?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <div class="content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <script>
        //widget
        (function(I,n,f,o,b,i,p){
        I[b]=I[b]||function(){(I[b].q=I[b].q||[]).push(arguments)};
        I[b].t=1*new Date();i=n.createElement(f);i.async=1;i.src=o;
        p=n.getElementsByTagName(f)[0];p.parentNode.insertBefore(i,p)})
        (window,document,'script','https://livechat...../script.js','liveChat');
        
        liveChat('init', 'ID......');
    </script>
</div>
```

This works, but not for mobile devices

[image]